# mysql query , with limit and order by , answers wrong

Tags: mysql, sql

guys i have a table for comments , i use this table to save comments of an application users for the posts , comments have likes also ,and i want to show the comments first order by like then order by date , but not all of comments at first , because there's can be very huge number of comments , i want to show the last 7 comments at first , and order it by like and then by time , to show the most liked comment at first and then the last new comments, and i also limit it to show 7 comment at first, but the limit function of mysql don't work currently for my query's , my comment table contain 20 comments .

sorry i can't upload image to here because lack of reputation so i uploaded them on my domain.

> table image: http://kurdsofts.net/first-mysql.jpg

i use this query to get the comment of a post , order by like and date, and limit it to 7 ( **this post has 7 comments** ):

```
SELECT * FROM `comments` WHERE `post_id` = 19 ORDER BY `likes` DESC,`date` DESC LIMIT 0,7
```

> result: http://kurdsofts.net/2nd-mysql.jpg

and the result is ok , no problem until now

but if i want to show the user the remain comments , with this query:

```
SELECT * FROM `comments` WHERE `post_id` = 19 ORDER BY `likes` DESC,`date` DESC LIMIT 1,7
```

> result: kurdsofts.net/srd-mysql.jpg

By default it should show the remain comment, and not show the prevue ones, but the answer again contains 7 comments.

Even for:

```
SELECT * FROM `comments` WHERE `post_id` = 19 ORDER BY `likes` DESC,`date` DESC LIMIT 2,7
```

> result: kurdsofts.net/4th-mysql.jpg

the answer for query contain 5 answers , and i don't know why
**there is only 7 comments for this post** , and for the **LIMIT 1,7** and **LIMIT 2,7** it should answer the empty table with no rows

can anyone help me , i will be really thankful to you if can help me solve this problem

Comment: this is my table: http://kurdsofts.net/first-mysql.jpg

Comment: please put table in text in question area above using the edit link under the question tags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was in mistake ,i didn't know the first argument of LIMIT , is offset , i think that's the page number :| so my query command had problem , and it was mistake
i found that , if i want to show the user the other 7 comments , or if there was no comments , query return empty rows i should multiple the page and the limited number of comments that i want to show

for the first 7 comments, my query should like:

> SELECT * FROM `comments` WHERE `post_id` = 19 ORDER BY `likes`
>   DESC,`date` DESC LIMIT 0,7

and to show another 7 comments my query should be like:

> SELECT * FROM `comments` WHERE `post_id` = 19 ORDER BY `likes`
>   DESC,`date` DESC LIMIT 7,7

Answer (score 0):

You want the most liked comment(s) first, followed by the newest.  Your `order by` is ordering all the comments by the same fields.

You need to find the one you want first, and then to include them in the `order by` explicitly:

```
SELECT c.*
FROM comments c JOIN
     (SELECT max(likes) as maxl FROM comments WHERE post_id = 19) as m
WHERE c.post_id = 19
ORDER BY (c.likes = m.maxl) DESC, c.date DESC
LIMIT 0, 7;
```

Comment: thanks for answering , but its now working for me , why , because post number 19 have 7 comments , on comments table , this query that you write now answer the right answer , but when i change the LIMITE 1,7 it don't answer the empty table , as i said this post has 7 comments only , so LIMITE 1,7 should answer no row , but it answer 7 rows again